# Расположить блоки в одну строку, используя сетки, без пробелов

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Использую `Bootstrap`, сетки. Располагаю следующие элементы в одну строку:

```
                 <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-2>
                           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="opeartion" value="Calculate">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="operation" value="Add">
                       </div>
                </div>
```

Кнопки не занимают всю отведенную им ширину. Оставшееся место дополняется пробелами.

Делать их шире не нужно,  сдвигать при помощи `margin` будет криво смотреться на маленьких экранах.

Как расположить кнопки справа друг за другом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap 4

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-end">
    <div class="row ml-0 mr-0">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="opeartion" value="Calculate"/>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="operation" value="Add"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap 3

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row ml-0 mr-0 pull-right">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="opeartion" value="Calculate"/>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="operation" value="Add"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Bootstrap Flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)

Comment: Flex появились только в 4 версии как я понимаю. В 3.7 использовать нельзя(

Comment: @Donatello вы можете использовать pull-right в bootstrap 3

Comment: Спасибо большое!